GlobalProtect VPN disables wifi on debian12
I'm running Debian 12 with KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.5.
I have trouble using GlobalProtect VPN by Palo Alto. ("GlobalProtect_deb-6.1.4.0-711.deb")
The package was installed using the instructions from the Website:
When connected by LAN, the VPN works just fine. But when on wifi, a loop is created.
First, the wired Ethernet Connection called "Io" is created and activated.
Second, the "Io" connections seems to trigger a disabling of the Wifi, that causing "Io" to be disabled.
Third, because "Io" is disabled, the Wifi gets reactivated and the cycle starts back at 1.
It seems weird, because when i have regular wired connection and Wifi at the same time, the Wifi doesn't get deactivated and they run next to each other having both network traffic.
Does anyone have a idea if this problem is related to the Package or just a configuration Issue with the OS?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Can't you ask PaloAlto Supporr it's too specific to the product which is closed source

Unfortunately to get customer support, you need to create a account, which can be only created providing the order number of the product.
Additionaly, when asking the University for support, they mention to not support Linux devices, even though they provide a Installation guide for the VPN.

Have a try at openconnect (check: https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/globalprotect.html ). It might not work for all cases (eg: might not for some MFA methods), but if it works, it will be much cleaner than the official tool provided.

I was able to fix the Issue using openconnect with the following script:
#!/bin/bash
#
MTU=1284
VPNPASSWORD=...
VPNUSER=...
# hipreport with openSUSE at libexec, other distros at lib
HIPREPORT=/usr/libexec/openconnect/hipreport.sh
DEADPEERSECS=30
IFACE=vpn0
echo $VPNPASSWORD | sudo /usr/sbin/openconnect --protocol gp --syslog --disable-ipv6 --csd-wrapper $HIPREPORT --interface $IFACE --mtu=$MTU --force-dpd=$DEADPEERSECS --user=$VPNUSER --passwd-on-stdin <vpn-url>.com

